# pyqt: return pressed signal for spinbox?

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals, signals-slots

There are signals ***valueChanged()*** and ***editingFinished()***, but I need perform my action only when key enter is pressed.

Is there any solution without reimplementing event handler?

I need to change focus to the next spinbox on pressed enter key.
Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Use `setKeyboardTracking(False)`

If keyboard tracking is disabled, the spinbox doesn't emit the valueChanged() signal while typing. It emits the signal later, when the return key is pressed, when keyboard focus is lost, or when other spinbox functionality is used, e.g. pressing an arrow key.

Comment: Added better description what I need.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I need to know when you hit enter even if you haven't changed the value, and valueChanged doesn't fire in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the underlying `QLineEdit` object which emits the desired `returnPressed()` signal:

```
spin_box = QSpinBox()   
spin_box.lineEdit().returnPressed.connect(self.spinBoxReturnPressed)

def spinBoxReturnPressed():
    ...
```